# Remove old icons in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell

I have been installing several version of [Komodo editor](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit/). (The installation consist of extracting a .tar.gz archive and then running an `.sh` script as root.)

Yesterday I installed Gnome 3.

Now I see in "Application" section of Gnome Shell both "Komodo Edit 7" and "Komodo Edit 5" despite of only "Komodo Edit 7" is installed.

How to remove the old icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because Komodo Edit sticks a `.desktop` file somewhere that Gnome Shell picks up, and it's not getting removed (probably for lack of an "uninstall" functionality). So, you'll have to dig through your folders a little bit to try to find where it's hiding. Here are some of the common places that I know of:

1. ~/.local/share/applications
2. /usr/share/applications
3. ~/desktop
4. ~/.wine/ (if it's a Wine program, it might be somewhere here)

According to [Gnome's documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en), 1 and 2 are the most likely places.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with wine application and I couldn't find the .desktop anywhere.

Wine a nasty, even if your `~/.local/share/applications` looks clean, you may want to check twice. I my case it was in a hidden subfolder:

```
~/.local/share/applications/.wine
```

With you may not notice at first. Bottom line is to always look for hidden folders.